# How to implement CRUD operations on Hierarchical and display it as property grid or treegrid?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Can Some one guide me, How to insert Hierarchical data like parent -> child -> grand child -> and so on .. , I need to display it as dynamic property grid or tree grid on UI.

```
   MyRootData
      MyChild1Data 
         MyGrandchild11Data
         MyGrandchild12Data
            MyGreatGrandchild121Data
         MyGrandchild13Data
      MyChild2Data
         MyGrandchild21Data
         MyGrandchild22Data
   MyRootData
      MyChild1Data 
         MyGrandchild11Data
         MyGrandchild12Data
            MyGreatGrandchild121Data
         MyGrandchild13Data
      MyChild2Data
         MyGrandchild21Data
         MyGrandchild22Data
```

I'm trying this in Spring mvc Hibernate, I'm kind of struck, Please help me. If any use full example/code base please share.

**Mode**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Textual_Req")
public class TextualReq {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue( generator = "increment" )
       @GenericGenerator( name = "increment", strategy = "increment" )
       @Column(name="ID")
       private int                    id;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="parent")
       private TextualReq                parent;
       @OneToMany( mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
       @Column(name="children")
       private Set<TextualReq> children = new HashSet<TextualReq>();
       @Column(name="data")
       private String                  data;
```

and DAO is

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<TextualReq> listTextualReq() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<TextualReq> textualReqList = session.createQuery("from TextualReq where parent is null").list();
        for(TextualReq root : textualReqList){
            logger.info("textualReqList ::"+root);
             root.display( "   " );
        }
        return textualReqList;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/textualReq", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listRequestReq(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("textualReq", new TextualReq());
        model.addAttribute("listtextualReq", this.textualReqService.listTextualReq());
        return "textualReq";
    }
```

Comment: This question is too broad and unclear. What ar you actually asking here? How to model a hierarchy using jpa/hibernate? How to show a hierarchy using Spring MVC/JSP? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with end to end using spring mvc and Hibernate. I will update post with some code.

Comment: What is your actual problem? Looks like a hierarchy model to me..

Comment: Tobb, I'm trying to implement a  grid  data in tree structure, something like   http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=PropertyGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

Comment: So it has nothing to do with JPA/Hibernate?